# How to track down corrupt PNG with bad CRC, when exception is caught within the JVM?

Tags: exception, logging, png, crc, corruption

My application uses hundreds of PNGs, and one of them causes `sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder$PNGException: crc corruption`
The stack-trace is logged to the console, but the exception is caught, and whatever it is, the image loads. No exception reaches my code, and the stack trace does not identify the PNG in any way.

I want to replace the broken PNG, but it is hard to find. I wrote a little app to load every png, and again, the exception is logged, but it can’t identify which one.
So I was wondering if it was a good idea to write a custom log Handler for only the java.desktop/sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder class, where instead of just logging, it throws an error, which stops my scanner at the bad file.
Is there a better way?

```
sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder$PNGException: crc corruption
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.getChunk(PNGImageDecoder.java:718)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.getData(PNGImageDecoder.java:726)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:253)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:269)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:212)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:176)
```

Comment: Can't you just run `pngcheck` on your images?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about pngcheck. I was distracted by the fact that the assets are bas64 encoded and stored elsewhere, not as regular PNGs. You reminded me that I can contact the team that provided the images, and ask them for the original files to validate.
It's not actually simple to re-encode all them into our persisted form, but it can't be worse then my idea above.